# C++ CreateFile function locks the file with UAC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, createfile

I'm working on a DLL file that extracts a resource file (.exe) from it to TEMP folder and executes it. The problem is it fails to execute the file unless the application that is using the DLL file is elevated (has administrator privileges). When I open TEMP folder from file explorer and double-click the extracted file, I get a UAC prompt. And when I click on "change when this notification appears" it is set to default (when a program tries to make changes to your computer). And I really don't understand why I get this notification because it's just a random file that runs without privileges on my PC unless it's extracted from the DLL. I use Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013. Here's a part of the code of the DLL file:

```
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(exePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) continue;
    WriteFile(hFile, pExeResource, SizeofResource(hinstDLL, hrsrc), NULL, NULL); 
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    if (!CreateProcess(exePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, tmpPath, &info, &pi))
        cout << "FAIL !\n";
    else cout << "SUCCESS !\n";
```

Comment: Where is the temp folder being created? Are your user account settings set up such that any exe file you try to run will prompt you for UAC auth? UAC is set based on a security scheme and is applied to certain folders controlled by the OS (such as `C:\Program Files`), not necessarily _how_ the file was created.

Comment: Why REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS? I think this needs admin rights

Comment: And for the UAC prompt, What account does the parent application run is? Is it the same as your logged in account? If no, then that could be a reason

Comment: @RyanJ The temp folder is located at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp and it's definately not a UAC protected folder. The file executes without prompt when it's not extracted from the DLL but prompts after it's extracted.

Comment: @GaneshR. The problem does not come from the CreateProcess function for shure because even when I manually double click the file from windows explorer it still prommpts.

Comment: @GaneshR. And it runs on the same account